# OS X Mavericks Screen brightness auto adjusting even when option is disabled

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Now I know from trying to find an answer to this to go uncheck the auto adjust box, since apparently it got checked when I updated to Mavericks, but now it seems my MacBook Pro has a mind of its own and still feels the need to auto adjust when I'm not doing anything.

I made sure 10 times at least that the auto adjust box wasn't checked, and it's not. So why is my Mac randomly doing this? (and btw, this only started today, and I got the update on the first day it was available)

Comment: Having this issue and unchecking the box doesn't help!

Answer (score 2):

I was just struggling with the same issue—it really annoyed the hell out of me. What helped me was a good ol' SMC reset:

See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964 on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I found that disabling "Automatic graphics switching" in the "Energy Saver" system preferences dialog fixed the problem (at least temporarily).

EDIT: Later in the evening, when I wanted to keep my brightness low, the bug recurred, then spontaneously disappeared again.

Answer (score 2):

It may have to do with your charger.
I had the same problem; look at your charger, the lights probably keep changing from green to orange to nothing. When you plug in your adapter it automatically adjusts your brightness, the bad contact makes it do this over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue when "upgrading" the OS.  It stopped auto-adjusting after I unchecked the box "Slightly dim the display while on battery power."  This is found in System Preferences / Energy Saver / Battery.  I know that's a different function, but it would appear there's a bug where the auto-adjust is tied to that checkbox instead of the one it's supposed to be tied to.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I've had this problem in Ventura, and the problem was that **System settings** > **Battery** > **Low Power mode** was set to **Only on Battery** and went dim every time I took the charger cable out, or every time I closed the lid whilst on battery.

[image: Screenshot of the Low Power Mode setting set to 'Only on Battery' in the Battery Settings]

Changing this option to **Never** fixed it. But really, FFS Apple ‍♂️

[image: Screenshot of the Low Power Mode setting set to 'Never' in the Battery Settings]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem - have just downloaded this ap and fingers crossed, it seems to be holding the brightness levels steady.

http://www.resexcellence.com/2013/01/29/control-mac-screen-brightness-with-shady/

Answer (score -4):

Are you sure?

System Preferences -> Displays -> Display -> Automatically adjust brightness

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP said she made sure 10 times it wasn't checked, and you ask "are you sure?"... hmm, are you sure?